# Find everything that's not an email address using only regex

Tags: javascript, regex, email

I need to find everything in a string that is not an e-mail address.

Here is my version of how to find an e-mail address.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-.]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6})$
```

I want to modify this regex to find the inverse--everything other than the e-mail address in any string.

---

###Example 1:
`asdasd`

###Example 2:
123@asd.com `sda`

---

**Note:**  I want to get `status == true` in the following line:

```
var status = myString.match(pattern matches everything that is not an email address);
```

###I can only change the pattern, nothing else!

Comment: So given a string `some text around a random username@hostname.tld email address` you want to retrieve: `some text around a random email address`?

Comment: @DavidThomas If there is any text around email adress I want to know it. I don't want to cut e-mail adress out of string!

Comment: @skmasq what should happen when you get a string "hello 123@asd.com world"?

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot I should get `true` and that is all.

Comment: Well then how about "hello world"?  Are you just looking for a regex that is `false` when the string contains nothing but email addresses and `true` in all other cases?

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot If it contains only email address I want it to give me `false`, but to give me `true` when `hello world` or `hello 123@abc.com world` !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official standard is known as [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4.1). Regex pattern for email address is then:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

More practical implementation of RFC 2822 (if we omit the syntax using double quotes and square brackets), which will still match 99.99% of all email addresses in actual use today, is:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

To get list of non-matching "words" from `myString` use JavaScript code:

```
var status = myString.match(/(?:\s|^)(?![a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\S+\b(?=\s|$)/ig);
```

Check [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/B3763/).

Answer (score 0):

You can call `replace`, with an empty string to remove the instances of the emails matching your pattern:

```
var noEmails = stringWithEmails.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-.]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6})/g, '');
```

Just note that I took out the leading `^` and trailing `$`. These were forcing the pattern to match the whole string (`^` is beginning of line, and `$` is end of line).

Answer (score 0):

```
var result=myString.replace('[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-.]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6})', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

string.replace(/[/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.([a-zA-Z]{2,6})]*/gi, '');

its worked

Answer (score -1):

Based on your edits, what you actually want is

```
var status = ! myString.match(email pattern)
```

That is, use your email pattern (or the giant thing posted by Ωmega) with the guards.  That will match everything that is *only* an email address.  That's exactly the opposite of what you want, so invert the boolean and you're done.

Comment: I can't use `!` in this problem.

Comment: This solution would return `false` for `Hallo john@doe.com`, which is not what OP wants...

Comment: @Ωmega No it wouldn't.  His regex would return `false` for that string (because his regex is guarded with `^` and `$`).  Then the false gets flipped and it returns `true`.

Comment: @skmasq Then you're out of luck.  Is this a homework problem or puzzle or something?  What's the context that's keeping you from being able to write any code?

Comment: @Ωmega OK, assuming that whitespace isn't counted when we say "not an email address", we just modify skmasq's regex by including optional whitespace: `^(?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}\s*)+$`

Comment: @Ωmega While it'd be trivial to account for that in what I posted, your assumption that empty string or pure-whitespace should be counted as an email address seems unfounded.